# how could I change animation of navigator

Tags: react-native

I notice that `Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight` has fade in effect, but I want animation act as `NavigatorIOS` default animation.

how could I control these properties directly or disable?

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

sorry to trouble, I find `Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump` act as NavigatorIOS default animation, and I decide to use `Navigator` to replace `NavigatorIOS` :)

Comment: This almost made me quit react native. The default PushFromRight feels horrible in iOS.